# Text search is not working in postgresql using GIN Index

Tags: postgresql

I have created a table in PostgreSQL as follows

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, timestamp bigint, data TEXT);
```

and added data

```
INSERT INTO test_table (timestamp, data) VALUES (1710240978464, 'how are u');
INSERT INTO test_table (timestamp, data) VALUES (1710240982533, 'where are u');
```

and created an index as follows

```
CREATE INDEX search_fulltext_idx ON test_table USING GIN(to_tsvector('english', data::text));
```

when I execute the query, in the explain plan I get Seq Scan, my query is not using the index

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE data @@ to_tsquery('english','how');
NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on test_table  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000001.52 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=51.640..51.641 rows=0 loops=1)
   Filter: (data @@ ''::tsquery)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 2
 Planning Time: 0.144 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 2
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.423 ms, Inlining 8.558 ms, Optimization 31.044 ms, Emission 11.861 ms, Total 51.886 ms
 Execution Time: 52.107 ms
(9 rows)
```

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

I want my query to use the index i created

Comment: The index won't kick in unless it speeds things up. For just two rows, it doesn't. Also, don't keep a `timestamp` as a `bigint` - you save zero space and complicate operations on them. If you upgrade to `timestamptz`, you'll even get time zone handling, also with zero added space/performance cost.

Answer (score 2):

1. The query needs to use the expression from your expression index for it to kick in.

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT * FROM test_table 
WHERE to_tsvector('english', data::text) 
   @@ to_tsquery('english','how');
```

2. You need more rows for Postgres to even consider speeding things up by using the index. At volumes this low it wouldn't make any difference, so it's not used even if you fix the query. Add more:

```sql
select setseed(.42);
insert into test_table (tstz,data)
select now()-random()*'1 year'::interval, 
        case when .05>random() then 'how r u' 
             else replace(gen_random_uuid()::text,'-',' ')
        end
from generate_series(1,1e5);
```

3. Your search phrase is unfortunate for the config you're using: *how* is a stop word, so it will be [wiped from the query phrase](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES):

   > `to_tsquery` normalizes each token into a lexeme using the specified or default configuration, and **discards any tokens that are stop words according to the configuration**
4. As a side-note: [don't](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29) keep a `timestamp` as a `bigint` - you save zero space and complicate operations on them. If you upgrade to `timestamptz`, you'll even get time zone handling, also with zero added space/performance cost.

```sql
alter table test_table 
  alter column "timestamp" 
    type timestamptz 
    using (to_timestamp("timestamp"));
alter table test_table rename column "timestamp" to tstz;
```

[Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/uAQMEaVY)

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Bitmap Heap Scan on test_table (cost=0.00..4.26 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1) |
| Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, data) @@ ''::tsquery) |
| -> **Bitmap Index Scan on search_fulltext_idx** (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
| Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, data) @@ **''::tsquery**) |
| Planning Time: 0.144 ms |
| Execution Time: 0.039 ms |

Notice how the index is now used, but the plan also shows your tsquery got wiped clean. As it turns out, the only usable thing based on which you can target `how are u` while using `'english'::regconfig`, is the `u`.